# How to sum results of sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT payable 
  FROM reservation 
  WHERE status LIKE 'confirmed'
```

Example result is [800,100,100]

What should I add to the query output a Total of 1000 (sum of result).

Comment: `SELECT sum(payable) FROM reservation WHERE status = 'confirmed'` - This is very basic SQL. I'd suggest you to go through some tutorials first.

Comment: If you had typed "SQL sum" into Google it would have given you the answer. Google is your friend. If you can't work Google, you won't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT sum(column) FROM Table WHERE condition`

This is called an aggregate function, there are many other usefuls functions you should know. Try W3 schools for more info: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM aggregate function to sum all values based on your condition.

```
SELECT sum(payable) 
FROM reservation 
WHERE status LIKE '%confirmed%' [OR --Any of your condition.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just building on what others have said:

```
SELECT sum(payable) as Total
  FROM reservation 
  WHERE status LIKE 'confirmed'
```